# Access Socket.io from everywhere in the Next.js project

Tags: reactjs, websocket, socket.io, next.js, vercel

I'm trying to create a website that shows logs from another project of mine. For that, I'm using Next.js.

What I intend, for now, is that when sending the following POST request I want the site to be automatically notified using Socket.io.

```
POST 'http://localhost:3000/api/log'

{"message": "Just another log."}
```

All of this is possible using 'yarn dev' ('node server.js'), however, when I build the project ('yarn build' & 'yarn start') I get an error while sending the above POST request saying the IO that I'm providing in 'socketIO.js' isn't defined.

How can I use socket.io (server side) in multiple files using Next.js?

All my code is on GitHub: https://github.com/yByonic/next-logs

Answer (score 0):

You need to modify your `start` script in your `package.json` to start your custom server rather than running `next start`.

```json
"start": "NODE_ENV=production node server.js"
```

You can check the [official custom server docs](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/custom-server) for more details.